# trouble writing a dql query

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, dql

I'm using a plugin to add tags to the contents of my database, and I'm having some difficulties in writing the following query :

I want the list of tags that are tagged to at least one published content, so I tried :

```
$this->tagsNumber = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tag')
->createQuery('t')
->select('t.name, count(tg.tag_id) as nbr')
->innerJoin('t.Tagging tg')
->innerJoin('Content c on c.id = tg.taggable_id')
->where('c.state = ?', 3)
->orderBy('nbr DESC, t.name')
->groupBy('tg.tag_id')
->execute();
```

But the relation between Tagging and Content isn't specified in the plugin, so Doctrine throws a "unkown relation alias" exception.

**EDIT**

I tried using the functions in *PluginTagTable.class.php* :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('tg.tag_id, t.name, COUNT(tg.id) AS t_count')
  ->from('Tagging tg, tg.Tag t, Content c on tg.model_id = c.id')
  ->where('c.state_id = ?', 3);

$this->etiquettesOrdre = PluginTagTable::getAllTagNameWithCount($q,Array('model' => 'Content', 'sort_by_popularity' => true));
```

But it still shows all tags, and weird numbers as the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ! I thought about downloading Apostrophe plugin and searching
for *getAllTagNameWithCount* calls

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Tagging tg, tg.Tag t, Content
c');
    $q->andWhere('c.id = tg.taggable_id and c.state_id = ?', 3);

    $this->tagsInOrder =
PluginTagTable::getAllTagNameWithCount($q,Array('model' => 'Content',
'sort_by_popularity' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good practice to:

1. Create a relation between them
2. Implement a [CountCache](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage) behavior

So in this case you can easily work with tagging routines.